# Equivalent for @CollectionElement for an attribute (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa, attributes, annotations

Is there something like the `@CollectionElement` annotation for simple attributes not beeing a list?

I would like to add an attribute to my entity not beeing a column but beeing a different table.

For example something like this (know that this does NOT work/exist..):

```
@ElementAttribute
@AttributeTable(
      name="THE_ATTRIBUTE_TABLE"
)
@Column(name="ATTRIBUTE")
private String attribute;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Pro JPA 2.0 book:

> entities may be mapped across multiple tables by making use of the
>   @SecondaryTable annotation and its plural @SecondaryTables

For example with famous Employee entity:

```
@SecondaryTable(name="EMP_ATTRIBUTES")
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id private int id;
  @Column(table="EMP_ATTRIBUTES")
  private String attribute;
}
```